# Symfony2: Multi-level parameters in YML

Tags: arrays, symfony, parameters, yaml, multi-level

Here is what I want to do. I've got some yml file like...

My custom yml file :

```
# app/config/sv_parameters.yml
parameters:
  sv_email:
    debug: "debug@debug.com"
    admin: "admin@admin.com"
    ...
```

The config.yml file, importing my custom params :

```
# app/config/config.yml
imports:
  - { resource: sv_parameters.yml }
...
```

The config_dev.yml, importing the config.yml, and using a sub-parameter of my custom yml file :

```
# app/config/config_dev.yml
imports:
- { resource: config.yml }

swiftmailer:
  delivery_address: "%sv_email.debug%"
```

But, when I `clear:cache` :

```
You have requested a non-existent parameter "sv_email.debug".
```

I know in PHP multi-level parameters are arrays. But does that mean we can access them in pure YML ?

I could write my `sv_email` parameters inline, but that's not as clean as multi levels..

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible to achieve in YML.
You have to move this nested variable to the upper level and then - include it in both needed places.

Comment: That's what I thought.. Do they plan to implement it in YML ? Because it would be much cleaner sometimes, instead of repeating `sv_email.debug` `sv_email.admin` `sv_email.client` ...

Comment: @Bonswouar I have absolutely no idea :)

Comment: No chance.  . is allowed in yaml parameters names so sv_email.client : value works just fine.  Just no way to convert arrays to a dot notation without a massive bc break.

Comment: On the other hand, the Symfony:DependencyInjection::load method allows you to add parameters to your container.  So you could convert sv_email into individual parameters if you want.  But I suspect you may find that to be more trouble than it's worth.